# Redshift Tables and Views DDL generation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am looking the best way to generate the tables through shell in Redshift. I am able to see the admin tables like v_generate_tbl_ddl, stl_ddltext but this is not solving my purpose. Do we have any options like below in redshift.

```
show create table table_name
or
show table table_name
```

My use case is to bring the latest ddls from prod and execute them in dev. I want to automate this process. Also in sql_ddltext, we are getting all ddls DROP/CREATE.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for 

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get full length of DDL for a table or any object in redshift / postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122298/how-to-get-full-length-of-ddl-for-a-table-or-any-object-in-redshift-postgresql)